# Loading configuration details from MySQL

Tags: go

I am trying to fetch the value from the database and want to load into my Go workspace, the data I am loading is a configuration data.
example - IP, log level, etc.

So when I run my Main Application, It should load those data from DB and should set somewhere, So that in my entire application I can use that.

DB looks something like this:

```
Parm_name | Param_val | param_id
IP        |127.0.0.1  | 205
log level |2          | 206
```

I am using Mysql DB, But not getting how to set these values to a struct maybe and access throughout the application.

Comment: You'll have to marshal it into an array of struct with fields `Param_name`, `Param_val` and `param_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer these code samples:

1. Using go sql driver 
   Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/V9DWcBTJL9j
2. Using go sql driver with package sqlx 
   Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/kXFIpjaX8-V

You can use sqlx package: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.
It provides method for parsing data in struct with the help of field tags.
Refer this link for an illustrated guide: https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/

Run these query in MySQL for data setup:

```
  create database stackoverflow;
  use stackoverflow;
  create table example(
      Parm_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      Param_val varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      Param_id integer primary key
      );
  insert into example values('IP','127.0.0.1',205);
  insert into example values('log level','2',206);
```